# Serial port programming VB6 via Win32 API

Tags: winapi, vb6, serial-port

I am interacting with a bill acceptor connected via serial in VB6 using the MSComm control. We're having some communication issues, and I have been tasked with using the Win32 API directly to interact with the serial port. I'm not quite sure where to begin. Any links, articles, or books would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "We're having some communication issues" - that's not very specific....

Comment: ... or you could post a question of the specific issue and get the answer here.  Just saying...

Comment: I appreciate that. The issues that we're having are irrelevant to this question, though -- they're basically third-party driver issues that we're going to avoid altogether by sending raw hex. My client has some issues with the MSComm control and so would prefer to work directly with the Win32 API. That's good enough for me.

Comment: If the driver issue is with a serial port adapter, you won't solve any problems by using the Win32 API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Serial Port Communication](http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/CommIO.aspx): perform serial port I/O without using the Microsoft Comm Control component

Comment: I like that one alot, although the documentation is sparse. We used this, it solved our issues, but we found and switched to ActiveComport (http://www.activexperts.com/files/activcomport/manual.htm) after that because it was a cleaner solution with better documentation. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Richard Grier

- Book *Visual Basic Programmer's guide to serial communications* available from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890422282) or [direct from author](http://www.hardandsoftware.net/)
- Sometimes still active on the [VB6 newsgroups](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?hl=en&enc_user=9wSHhhgAAAC5zRPsccoMXKBsTUoOhjwFZkhl-c3KK5iRXwYE7Av3CQ) - try asking there

Comment: Fine for VB6, but his solution doesn't completely solve the issues with the .NET serial port class.  His book is extremely dated, and while most of it still applies, look elsewhere if you end up upgrading this project to .NET.  Nice guy though!

Comment: @Brad The question is tagged VB6

Comment: yes, I completely agree.  I was just pointing it out, so that if they decide to go to .NET later, they can add the serial port to the list of things they will need to completely redo.